# CSS float / inline block issue

Tags: html, layout, css-float, css

- Would you please examine [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znPGj/)?
- Resize the width of the "result" frame.
- Observe that the layout of the boxes switches between 2 and 3
  columns.

This glitch is anoying I want the layout to look like this and stay like this even when I resize the window:

```
_________
| ▄ ▄ ▄ |
| 1 2 3 |
| ▄ ▄ ▄ |
| 4 5 6 |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Could you alter the HTML/CSS to perfect the layout and get rid of the glitch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/znPGj/3/ fixes it by setting a height in px on the img boxes

Comment: I was thinking of a solution that would enable the pictures to scale. However, I guess this could be an option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/znPGj/4/ css:

```
a {
    float:left; 
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
    color: #000;
    font: medium sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
a:nth-child(4){clear:both}
img {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all the `img` in a `div` and set a specific `width` on the `div`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/znPGj/5/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dropping the width to 32%?  Worked for me, but I didn't test on many browsers.